# pop af and flags

Tags: emulation, z80

I'm writing a Z80 emulator in Swift for Mac OS and I have got as far as implementing the 16 bit pop instruction. The documentation I have found (i.e. The Z80 CPU User manual UM008011-0816 and also this document about [undocumented Z80 instructions](http://www.z80.info/zip/z80-documented.pdf)) says that the flags are not affected by `pop dd` (where dd is a 16 byte register).

However, one of the pop instructions is `pop af` (opcode `0xf1`) where `f` in `af` is the flags register. Does the Z80 toss the low byte or does it set the flags in apparent contradiction to the documentation.

Comment: When it says that it doesn't affect the flags, it means that it doesn't affect flags *incidentally* in the way that many other instructions do, not that it won't write to the flags register if that's what it's told to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the main purposes of the `POP AF` and the `EX AF,AF'` instructions actually is to be able to move the flags to a safe place and restore them afterwards. So, opposite to what you have read, `POP AF` actually *does* affect the flags (but only if the destination register is AF). Apparently, the writers assumed this as a given.

[Here](http://www.z80.info/z80sflag.htm) is an article on how Z80 instructions affect the flags.

Comment: Thanks. I'd sort of come to the same conclusion especially as I noticed that the official manual doesn't even mention that sp changes as a result of the pop.

Comment: Also note that the flags register holds a full 8 bits.  So a sequence like "PUSH BC; POP AF; PUSH AF; POP BC" will not alter BC even though 2 bits of the flag register are officially undefined.

Comment: @GeorgePhillips Oh well, yes. POPing single bits would be a bit "extravagant"

Comment: @tofro What I mean is that you could reasonably think that bit 3 and bit 5 of the flag register are always zero or one or undefined.  That would cost the hardware nothing as it simply wouldn't have storage for those bits.  Thus passing data through F register might result in bit 3 and bit 5 being changed.

Comment: @GeorgePhillips Ah, geddid. Yes, that's true. You shouldn't use AF to save some other register from the stack.

Comment: @tofro Other way around.  As an emulator writer your might think that passing data through AF will corrupt it.  However, it will not be a problem on a real Z-80 and, thus, should not be a problem on an emulator.

Comment: @GeorgePhillips Bits 3 and 5 are technically undefined but I found a document on the Internet that describes what happens to them (in the Z80A at least). I'm not sure if the behaviour is consistent across models though.